# Clipping polygon precisely to raster (extent) using GDAL?

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, clip

I need to clip a vector layer to the extent of a raster. It has to be very precise that's why I would not want to draw a polygon myself (and clip the two polygons). There seem to be some ways to clip a raster to a polygon but I have difficulties to find a solution to clip a polygon to a raster. I already tried to create a polygon out of my raster several times in ArcGIS and R, so I could clip the result. But every time it crashes because the raster is to big. There must be a simple way to solve this, and somehow I can just not see it at the moment.

How can I do this using GDAL?

Comment: If you also want to ask about software other than GDAL please do that using one question per software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use GDAL's ogr2ogr utility (http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to clip a polygon by an extent. If you have GDAL for Python you can use something similar to this script to perform the task:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import subprocess

# define file paths
inRasterPath = 'C:/path/to/file.tif'
inVectorPath = 'C:/path/to/file.shp'
outVectorPath = 'C:/path/to/file.shp' 

# get the extent of the raster
src = gdal.Open(inRasterPath)
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
sizeX = src.RasterXSize * xres
sizeY = src.RasterYSize * yres
lrx = ulx + sizeX
lry = uly + sizeY
src = None

# format the extent coords
extent = '{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(ulx, lry, lrx, uly);

# make clip command with ogr2ogr - default to shapefile format
cmd = 'ogr2ogr ' + outVectorPath + ' ' + inVectorPath + ' -clipsrc ' + extent

# call the command
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

If you don't have GDAL for Python, you can use the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS and run the `gdalinfo` command on your raster to get the extent and then the `ogr2ogr` command to clip the vector to the extent noted from the gdalinfo result with the `-clipsrc` flag.

Make sure your polygon and raster file are in the same projection.