# Cut shapefile to raster in Python using GDAL/OGR

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, gdal, ogr

I'm using a huge shapefile containing the coastlines of the world:

[image]

And want to cut out polygons from the shapefile to fit to my geotif like so (the blue polygons represents the cut out ones):

[image]

I want to do this in order to mask the land afterwards (and maybe extent the covered area if it doesn't properly cover land).

How does one do this in Python using GDAL/OGR libraries (performance do matter)?

The shapefile consists of many polygons and I'm not sure whether merging all of this to one feature will speed up performance?

One could get the bounding box of the raster, but how to go from there I'm not sure of:

```
# Raster image to clip
InputImage = 'Geotif.tif'

# Polygon shapefile used to clip
Shapefile = 'worldcoastlines.shp'

rasterFormat = 'GTiff'
vectorFormat = 'ESRI Shapefile'

# Open datasets
raster = gdal.Open(InputImage, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
wktproj = raster.GetProjectionRef()
sref = osr.SpatialReference()
sref.ImportFromWkt(wktproj)

ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = raster.GetGeoTransform()
lrx = ulx + (raster.RasterXSize * xres)
lry = uly + (raster.RasterYSize * yres)
```

Comment: Maybe get the bounding box of the raster and then use that one to perform a clip?

Comment: @BritishSteel Added it in the question. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I can't add a comment yet, otherwise I would put this there. Your post is really similar to this problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275086/clipping-polygon-precisely-to-raster-extent-using-gdal/275089#275089 You can use ogr2ogr to accomplish this.